# Generating access statistics over time periods in django

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement statistic for an existing site, but I'm completly lost, don't know which model structure to choose. Now what I have (the relevant parts of the model):

```
class nFile(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  upfile = models.FileField()
  downloaded = models.IntegerField() # here I count the downloads
  viewed = models.IntegerField() # here I count the quickviews
  comment = models.CharField(max_length=400)
  tags = TagField()
  category = models.ForeignKey(FileCategory)
```

what I want, is to produce statistic with columns like this:

```
file name | downloads for the last 30 days | downloads for the last 7 days | downloads to date | category
```

with the possibility of ordering by the three middle column values.

so example:

```
sunshine.bmp | 12 | 7 | 20 | pics
cake.txt     | 13 | 5 | 15 | receipes
...
```

I also want to count the unique visitors. So my first impression was to implement a new model like this:

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
  session_key = models.CharField( max_length = 40 )
  enter_date = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, editable = False )
  leave_date = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, editable = False )
```

and add to the nFile model two fields:

```
  downloaders = models.ManyToManyField( Visitor )
  viewers = models.ManyToManyField( Visitor )
```

I can manage every field of this new class, and I think every info is in the database (now it is SqLite3, on production Postgre ), but what queries should I use. Maybe I should use a different model, or put a new Field to the nField class, I don't know.

I also want to have a statistic similar above, for categories, and tags like:

```
category | downloads for the last 30 days | downloads for the last 7 days | downloads to date
```

and

```
tag | downloads for the last 30 days | downloads for the last 7 days | downloads to date
```

I think I should use aggregation and filtering, but couldn't find the magic combination.

**Edit 1:**

No reactions, so I try to clarify what do I want.

a query like this would give me

```
q = nFile.objects.annotate(dcount=Count('downloaders'))
```

a list of nfiles, with the total number of downloaders, something like this:

```
q[0].title = sunshine.bmp
q[0].dcount = 20
q[1].title = cake.txt
q[1].dcount = 15
```

right? but I don't want to just annotate all of the downloaders, I want to annotate the Count the visitors whose enter_date is between now and now-timedelta(days=7)

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking. You seem to have some decent ideas of where to go. What is the problem you have with going forward from here?

Comment: @Marcin I don't know how to build a queryset which produce the desirable result. I'm also not sure that I'm on the right way of solving this task (I mean the Visitor model itself or/and the connection to the nFile model maybe not good. ).

Comment: I suggest putting any clarifications in your question. There's nothing wrong with extensively editing your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the feedback, if I get other suggestions like your I'll try to clarify it.. ( for me its clear ;) )

Comment: You are not the intended audience. It doesn't matter if it is clear to you.

Comment: @Marcin yes, I know. That's why i put there a smiley.

Comment: Change the title to something related to your problem "generating access statistics over time periods in django" or something similar

Comment: @RobOsborne Thanks, I changed the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever I need statistics like this I create a class manager and annotate using raw sql:

```
class nFileManager(models.Manager):
    def with_stats(self):
        return self.extra(
            'downloads_07n_day': """
                 SELECT COUNT(distinct d.id) FROM myapp_downloads d
                 WHERE d.nfile_id == myapp_nfile.id
                 AND d.date > now() - interval 7 days
             """,
            'downloads_30_day': """
                 SELECT COUNT(distinct d.id) FROM myapp_downloads d
                 WHERE d.nfile_id == myapp_nfile.id
                 AND d.date > now() - interval 30 days
             """
        )
```

Then you add that manager to your object:

```
def nFile(...):
    ...
    objects = nFileManager()
```

Now you can apply with_stats to objects to get those values:

```
nFile.objects.with_stats().filter(...)
```

It works with some aggregations as well (to get your categories).

Note this makes your through tables more complicated, you'll need an explicit table with date and id on those as well.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. I'm just wondering is there any "django way" of doing this? In this case the performance is not important, just the admin can see the stats.

Comment: Not without having lots of queries.  Basically you need to have a query for each annotation (30 day, 7 day, ...) and then merge the results.  Gathering by category requires a query per query for each category.  Quickly grows out of hand.  There are also some shortcomings in the Django aggregations that you will bump into.